# Order/randomize/convert array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got this:

```
a = [[123,1],[124,1],[125,1],[126,2],[127,3],[128,3]]
```

And I would like to turn a into b:

- ordered by value
- random within array of value

// updated:

```
b = [[124,123,125],[126],[128,127]]
```

How to do this in ruby? Im using rails.

Comment: I don't think your result brackets match up - do you mean: [[124,123,125],[126],[127,128]] ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to convert a to b?

Comment: your `b = [[124,123,125]],[[126]],[[128][127]]]` is illegal in ruby.  maybe you mean `[[123, 124, 125], [126], [127, 128]]`

Comment: yes, i apologize. I corrected the b in the question above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.group_by(&:last).
  sort_by(&:first).
  map(&:last).
  map {|el| el.map(&:first).shuffle }
```

Comment: You could even get rid of the first map by using the result of group_by directly as a hash `a.group_by(&:last).map {|_,v| v.map(&:first).shuffle }`

Comment: doesn't it need to be sorted?  If a is `a = [[30,100],[123,1],[124,1],[125,1],[126,2],[127,3],[128,3]]` then the result is `[[30], [123, 124, 125], [126], [128, 127]]`

Comment: 動靜能量, what do you mean? it is sorted by the second argument right?

Comment: shouldn't the 30 go to the end?

Comment: Nice one! Just to be cheeky I came up with an alternate version with one less call:  a.group_by(&:last).values.map{|x| x.map(&:first).shuffle }

Comment: ah, yes, its morning and im awake now. i see your point. @動靜能量, u're right. @Jörg, thx for improving! I didnt see it as much of a problem as the sorting on the last argument is done by sql. but i'll put it as a security check anyway. @Dave, haha, this rails community is crazy! :) thx!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is:

```
a = [[123,1],[124,1],[125,1],[126,2],[127,3],[128,3]]

a = a.sort {|d, e| d[1] <=> e[1]}

prev = a[0][1]; result = []; group = [];

a.each do |e|
  if e[1] == prev
    group << e[0]
  else
    result << group.shuffle
    group = [e[0]]
    prev = e[1]
  end
end
result << group

p result
```

run:

```
$ ruby t.rb
[[125, 123, 124], [126], [127, 128]]
```

Comment: ok, so you would say: randomize a first. Then do a.each as you stated? the random within group is important

Comment: then you can add shuffle to group when adding to result

Answer (score 0):

```
a.reduce([]){|m,i|m[i[1]]=(m[i[1]]||[])<<i[0];m}.compact
```

Comment: thx Lars! Though I prefer to have a bit more human language so it actually makes sense to me while re-reading the code some time :)